# Apple Airpods - Android - When using for calls, does sound come through both Airpods, or just one?

Tags: audio, android, call, airpods

When using Airpods on an Android device (I am specifically using a Google Pixel 2), does sound come through both of the Airpods when making/receiving calls? Or, does only one of the Airpods play sound when on a call?

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or do you have a problem with your AirPods?

Answer (score 1):

AirPods work like standard bluetooth headphones on non-Apple devices. You'll hear sound through both AirPods on calls.

I'd encourage you to visit your local Apple Store and do an in-store demo using your phone to see if they're right for you. Alternatively you can have them shipped to you and return them within 2 weeks if you aren't satisfied.

[Set up instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207010#manual)

Comment: Can someone edit this to show if tap controls or voice commands work with android OS or hardware never / sometimes / generally / always?This could be a good general answer about Android and AirPods with a little extra concrete details

Comment: @bmike I wonder if this question should be migrated to https://android.stackexchange.com/ given that it's unlikely any of us use android?

Comment: I don’t think so, but if you have someone in that chat room say they’d take the migration and you want it - there - we could look at it. I’m trying to get a canonical question here answering the broader feature question of what works and what won’t. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326260/