# How compatible are Apple Airpods with Android phones?

Tags: android, airpods

I want to buy the AirPods but I only have an Android phone.

The functions that would be ideal:

- Stereo and mono sound works like iOS when you take one AirPod out and charge it and then put both AirPods back in your ears.
- Tap function - is there no / some / complete parity with iOS tap features
- Voice assistant - is there no / some / complete parity with Hey Siri and tap / manual Siri voice commands

Basically, how feature compatible is the Android OS and hardware with AirPod features beyond simple Bluetooth microphone and headphone function?

Comment: Looking to see if we have a canonical question that answers some specific details that I’ll add here. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/324311/ Forgive the feature edit - if you only have one of these narrow feature requests - please roll back or revise my edits. We can ask a different canonical question to cover the bases on a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

They work like standard BT headsets for music and calls. Mono is played on both ears. Haven’t seen any usable tap/click functionality on non-apple devices, no voice assistant either. That last one is probably because Siri initial processing is mostly on-device, which other platforms don’t have.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's Airpods are standard bluetooth headphones and (from what I have seen online) should work fine with most modern Android-based phones.

A simple search online for:

```
apple airpods "android"
```

Will yield a number of helpful results

Comment: Asking me to Google something goes against the StackExchange spirit :)